# Extracting specific data from nested list

Tags: r, list, nested

I am trying web scraping of movies of 2019 from IMDB. I am extracting the Director's name from a nested list.
Now, the issue is the name of the Directors are not given for all the movies but for selected few, hence I need to extract the Director's name where ever the term 'Director:\n' appears.

***The nested list is as follows:***

```
[[1]]
[1] "Henry Cavill,Freya Allan,Anya Chalotra,Mimi Ndiweni\n"

[[2]]
[1] "\n"                                                          
[2] "Director:\nJ.J. Abrams"                                    
[3] "|"                                                           
[4] "Stars:\nCarrie Fisher,Mark Hamill,Adam Driver,Daisy Ridley\n"

[[3]]
[1] "Pedro Pascal,Carl Weathers,Rio Hackford,Gina Carano\n"

[[4]]
[1] "\n"                                                                       
[2] "Director:\nTom Hooper"                                                    
[3] "|"                                                                        
[4] "Stars:\nFrancesca Hayward,Taylor Swift,Laurie Davidson,Robbie Fairchild\n"

[[5]]
[1] "Guy Pearce,Andy Serkis,Stephen Graham,Joe Alwyn\n"

[[6]]
[1] "\n"                                                                   
[2] "Director:\nMichael Bay"                                              
[3] "|"                                                                    
[4] "Stars:\nRyan Reynolds,Mélanie Laurent,Manuel Garcia-Rulfo,Ben Hardy\n"
```

Here as one can see, the Director's name appears in an alternate manner but this is just for example purpose. Thanks in advance.

Expected Output:

directors_data
NA,"J.J. Abrams",NA,"Michael Bay"

Comment: Can you share the data using `dput` and show the expected output as well for the given example? I mean where the term "Director" is not present do you need `NA` or ignore the entry altogether?

Comment: I want the NA so that the final data frame has no row count count issue.

Comment: Why "Tom Hooper" is not in the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, where you can use use the method `grep`+`gsub`, or the method `regmatches` + `gregexpr`.

Assuming you data is a list `lst`, then you can try the following code to extract the director's name:

```
sapply(lst, function(x) ifelse(length(r <- grep("Director",x,value = T)),gsub("Director:\n","",r),NA))
```

or

```
sapply(lst, function(x) ifelse(length(r<-unlist(regmatches(x,gregexpr("(?<=Director:\n)(.*)",x,perl = T)))),r,NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_extract` to extract string and `map` to loop over each element in the list

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

map_chr(list_df, ~{temp <- na.omit(str_extract(.x, "(?<=Director:\n)(.*)")); 
                   if(length(temp) > 0) temp else NA})

#[1] NA            "J.J. Abrams" NA            "Tom Hooper"
```

**data**

Since you did not provide a reproducible example I created one myself.

```
list_df <- list("Henry Cavill,Freya Allan,Anya Chalotra,Mimi Ndiweni\n", 
c("\n", "Director:\nJ.J. Abrams", "|", "Stars:\nCarrie Fisher,Mark Hamill,Adam Driver,Daisy Ridley\n"
), "Pedro Pascal,Carl Weathers,Rio Hackford,Gina Carano\n", 
c("\n", "Director:\nTom Hooper", "|", "Stars:\nFrancesca Hayward,Taylor Swift,Laurie Davidson,Robbie Fairchild\n"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
directors_data <- gsub("Director:\n", "",

                       unlist(Map(function(x){x[2]}, list_df)), fixed = TRUE)
```

Base R solution not using unlist and using mapply not Map:

```
directors_data <- gsub(".*\\\n", "",

                       mapply(function(x){x[2]}, list_df, SIMPLIFY = TRUE))
```

Base R solution if pattern appears at different indices per list element:

```
directors_data <- gsub(".*\\\n", "",

                       mapply(function(x) {

                         ifelse(length(x[which(grepl("Director", x))]) > 0,

                                x[which(grepl("Director", x))],

                                NA)}, list_df, SIMPLIFY = TRUE))
```